# What is Lobot's timeline with Lando?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

This question is in regards to the canon history of Lobot. The comic mini-series *Lando* shows that Lando has known Lobot for a long time, as they consider each other brothers. However, when Lando appears in *Star Wars Rebels*, Lobot is nowhere to be found. So, when did they meet?

Comment: It’s not really clear at this point. Perhaps we’ll be told in the Han Solo solo film. He doesn’t know Lobot in *Rebels*, he knows him in the original trilogy. The *Lando* comics take place after the Battle of Yavin, so....

Comment: @Adamant I don't think we can conclusively say he doesn't know Lobot in Rebels.  All we can say thus far is Lobot hasn't appeared in Rebels.  Lando has only appeared in person once but has spent time off planet.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I agree. I probably should have said we don’t know whether he knows Lobot in *Rebels*.